# Having issues in adding newline when using sed to append new line after matching a pattern

Tags: sed

I am using below command to search for pattern (Rel_Tag_St_bit) and then append the following line in file:

```
sed -i -e '/Rel_Tag_St_bit/a\'$'\n''\ methods.mavenWithGoals("mvn so:s -f abc/pom.xml")' file
```

Once this line is added, I need to have newline character because I see the next line appended after the newly added line on the same line.

Sample input:

```
Line1 (pattern match)managedScripts.Rel_Tag_St_bit("${env.templo_directory}/version.txt")
Line 2 (append ) methods.mavenWithGoals("mvn so:s -f abc/pom.xml") methods.mavenWithGoals("deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=)
Line 3 (appears on second line itself)
```

So the third line here [methods.mavenWithGoals("deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=)] appears on the second appended line.

Sample output:

```
1)managedScripts.Rel_Tag_St_bit("${env.templo_directory}/version.txt")
2)methods.mavenWithGoals("mvn so:s -f abc/pom.xml")
3)methods.mavenWithGoals("deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=)
```

Comment: Show some sample input and your corresponding desired output.  Also, since different versions of sed handle newlines differently, specify what version of sed you have (GNU or BSD) or, if you don't know that, then specify which platform you are on (MacOS, Linux, BSD, Win...).

Comment: @John1024 I am using MacOS and sample input have been provided but I am not able to format it correctly.

Comment: @user312307 use code formatting: http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: To be useful to us, the sample input needs to look like you actual input, no added discussion or parenthetical thoughts or line numbers or anything.  Likewise, the corresponding sample output needs to look like the actual output that you want.   Otherwise, it leaves us guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your original file contained:

```
$ cat file
managedScripts.Rel_Tag_St_bit("${env.templo_directory}/version.txt")
methods.mavenWithGoals("deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=)
```

You can modify it with:

```
$ sed -e '/Rel_Tag_St_bit/a\'$'\nmethods.mavenWithGoals("mvn so:s -f abc/pom.xml")\n' file
managedScripts.Rel_Tag_St_bit("${env.templo_directory}/version.txt")
methods.mavenWithGoals("mvn so:s -f abc/pom.xml")
methods.mavenWithGoals("deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=)
```

That is using the shell (bash,ksh,zsh) C-strings `$'...'` to introduce newlines.

Comment: Thanks..This works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -i -e '/Rel_Tag_St_bit/G;s/\n/&methods.mavenWithGoals("mvn so:s -f abc/pom.xml")/' file
```

Here you append a newline `G` at the end of the desired line `/Rel_Tag_St_bit/`, then stick the desired text after the newline you just added with that `G` command. Since the newline is added conditionally, so the `s///` command won't fire for the noninteresting lines and `sed` would let them pass on as is.